# Calculating the derivative of a one-dimensional ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, partial-derivative

> Let $\phi(t, x_0)$ be a solution of the one-dimensional differential equation
>   $$\dot{x}= f(x),$$
>   with $\phi(0, x_0) = x_0$. Show that its derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}\phi(t, x_0)$ is given by
>   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}\phi(t, x_0) = exp \Big(\int_{0}^{t}f'(\phi(s, x_0))ds\Big)$$

Here in my proposed solution.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have

$$\phi(t, x_0)=x_0 + \int_{0}^{t}f(\phi(s, x_0))ds$$

because $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial t}(t, x_0)=f(\phi(t, x_0))$ and $\phi(0, x_0)=x_0$.

If we differentiate this solution with respect to $x_0$, we obtain via the chain rule that

$$\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x_0}(t, x_0)=1 + \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_0}}(\phi(s, x_0))
\cdot \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x_0}(s, x_0)ds$$

Let $$z(t)= \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x_0}(t, x_0)$$

Then,

$$z(0)= \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x_0}(0, x_0)=1$$

by the analysis above. Therefore, if we differentiate $z$ with respect to $t$, we find that

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
z'(t) & = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_0}}(\phi(t, x_0)) \cdot \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x_0}(t, x_0)\\
 & = \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_0}}(\phi(t, x_0)) \cdot z(t)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We do not have an explicit solution to $\phi(t,x_0)$, but the above equation tells us that $z(t)$ solves the following differential equation,

$$z'(t)= \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_0}}(\phi(t, x_0)) \cdot z(t)$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{dz}{dt}= \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_0}}(\phi(t, x_0)) \cdot z(t)$$

Rearranging terms produces

$$\frac{1}{z(t)}{dz}= \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_0}}(\phi(t, x_0))dt$$

Hence,

$$ln(z(t))= \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_0}}(\phi(s, x_0))ds$$

And taking the exponential of both sides produces

$$z(t)= exp \Big(\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_0}}(\phi(s, x_0))ds\Big)$$

As $z(t)=\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x_0}(t, x_0)=exp \Big(\int_{0}^{t}f'(\phi(s, x_0))ds\Big)$, we are done.

I'm not certain if there is a more direct approach. Please let me know if the solution can be improved.

Comment: Could you correct the missing partial derivative in the chain rule application and regard that $f$ has the variable $x$, thus its derivative is for $x$, not $x_0$? Btw., exponentiation is different from multiplying with $e$.

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with the partial derivative. Does $\phi(t, x_0)=1 + \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_0}}(\phi(s, x_0))
\cdot \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x}(s, x_0)ds$ need to be changed to $\phi(t, x_0)=1 + \int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(\phi(s, x_0))
\cdot \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial x_0}(s, x_0)ds$?

Comment: Yes, that too, but on the left side the derivative is missing.

Comment: Yes, I had that correct in my original solution and forgot to write it down. I don't see why I would need to write $\frac{\partial {f}}{\partial x}$ instead of $\frac{\partial {f}}{\partial x_0}$, as $f(\phi(s, x_0))$ is being differentiated with respect to $x_0$.

Comment: Why not to differentiate your equation directly? $\dot x=f(x)\implies \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_0}=f'(x)\frac{\partial x }{\partial x_0}$, which immediately yields the required conclusion?

Comment: @Axion004 : No, that was true before you applied the chain rule. If you want to stick to symbols that are actually present, then it should be $\dfrac{∂f}{∂ϕ}(ϕ(s,x0))$, but in the end it is just $f'(ϕ(s,x0))$

Comment: @Artem : I follow why $\dot{x} = f(x) \implies \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial x_0}=f'(x)\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial x_0}$, although I don't understand how that leads to the desired solution.

Comment: This is exactly your equation starting with $z'(t)=...$

Comment: I see, I didn't need to start from the FTC in the first step. I could have started from $z(t)$, integrated with respect to $t$, and then found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above, here is a shorter answer:

As $\dot{x}=f(x) \implies \frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)$, we can differentiate both sides with respect to $x_0$ to form

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{x_0}}=\frac{df(x)}{dx}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{x_0}}=f'(x)\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{x_0}}$$

Therefore, as $\phi(t,x_0)$ is a solution to the ODE, we know that $x(t)=\phi(t,x_0)$. Hence,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{x_0}}(t,x_0)=f'(\phi(t,x_0))\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{x_0}}(t,x_0)$$

Now, let $z(t)=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{x_0}}(t,x_0)$. Then,

$$\frac{d}{dt}z(t)=f'(\phi(t,x_0))z(t)$$

So,

$$\frac{1}{z(t)}d{z(t)}=f'(\phi(t,x_0))dt$$

Hence, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$ln(z(t))=\int_0^t{f'(\phi(s,x_0))ds}$$

Therefore, if we take the exponential of both sides,

$$z(t)=exp\Big(\int_0^t{f'(\phi(s,x_0))ds}\Big)$$

So, $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{x_0}}(t,x_0)=exp\Big(\int_0^t{f'(\phi(s,x_0))ds}\Big)$.